# how to detect user current location authorized and reload data in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation, cllocationmanager

In the view didload method
I'm calling

```
  /**initialize location manager**/
    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    //set the delegate for the location manager
    //locationManager.delegate = self;
    // set your desired accuracy
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

To get permission from user while the `Tableview` is loading.

How can I catch the event that user authorized the app to get permission at anytime

```
status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized
```

then reload table?

Answer (score 1):

Register a `CLLocationManagerDelegate` on your location manager instance with  `-[CLLocationManager setDelegate:]`. Your delegate should implement [`-[CLLocationManagerDelegate locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidChangeAuthorizationStatus%3a).